# How to create sublists out of a list with strings?

Tags: python, list

Having a Python list like the following one:

```
list1 = [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ]
```

How can I obtain sub-lists for each character of the strings ?

```
list3 = [ ["a"], ["b"], ["c"] ]

list4 = [ ["d"], ["e"], ["f"] ]

list5 = [ ["g"], ["h"], ["i"] ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781225/4650634

Answer (score 2):

**Do not generate variables programmatically**, this leads to unclear code and is often a source of bugs, **use a container instead** (dictionaries are ideal).

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
list1 = [ "abc", "def", "ghi" ]

lists = {'list%s' % (i+3): [[e] for e in s]] 
         for i,s in enumerate(list1)}
```

output:

```
>>> lists
{'list3': [['a'], ['b'], ['c']],
 'list4': [['d'], ['e'], ['f']],
 'list5': [['g'], ['h'], ['i']]}

>>> lists['list3']
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

*NB. you could also simply use the number as key (3/4/5)*

Answer (score 2):

To get a `list` from a string use `list(string)`

```
list('hello') # -> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

And if you want  to wrap the individual characters in a list do it like this:

```
[list(c) for c in 'hello'] # --> [['h'], ['e'], ['l'], ['l'], ['o']]
```

But that is useful only if you want to change the list afterward.

Note that you can index a string like so

```
'hello'[2] # --> 'l'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to break a list then break it into character list.

```
list1 = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
list3 = list(list1[0])
list4 = list(list1[1])
list5 = list(list1[2])
```